# How to check if input meets the criteria?

Tags: java

Part of my assignment was to have the user input an Eployee Id between 0-9 and contains a letter between A-M(ex. 999-M), and then if it doesn't meet one of the criteria it is supposed to throw an error code using an exception class. I figured out how to check the Id, but only works with the number part. I have no clue how to check if the input also meets the letter criteria. I know it has something to do with employee Id being an int and not a string, but when I attempted to fix it. I almost messed my whole code up. Any help would be appreciated.
My main code:

```
package payrollexceptions;

import java.util.Scanner;


public class PayRollExceptions
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        Payroll employee = new Payroll();
        String name;
        int employeeId;
        double payRate;

        System.out.print("Enter the employee's name: ");
        employee.setName(keyboard.nextLine());

        System.out.print("Enter employee number, (ex. 999-M): ");
        employee.setEmployeeId(keyboard.nextInt());

        System.out.print("Enter the employee's hourly rate: ");
        employee.setPayRate(keyboard.nextDouble());

        System.out.print("Enter the number of hours the employee has worked: ");
        employee.setHours(keyboard.nextInt());


        System.out.println("\n" + employee.getName());
        System.out.println("-----------");
        System.out.println("ID: " + employee.getEmployeeId());
        System.out.println("Pay rate: $" + employee.getPayRate());
        System.out.println("Hours worked: $" + employee.getHours());
        System.out.println("Gross pay: $" + employee.getGrossPay());
    }
}
```

The code that involves setting the employeeId:

```
package payrollexceptions;

public class Payroll
{
    private int employeeId, hours;
    private double payRate;
    private String name;

    public Payroll() {}

    public Payroll(String name, int employeeId, double payRate)
    {
        try
        {
            if(name == "")
            {
                throw new EmptyNameException();
            }

            setName(name);

            if(employeeId <= 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidEmployeeIdException();
            }

            setEmployeeId(employeeId);

            if(payRate < 0 || payRate > 25)
            {
                throw new InvalidPayRateException();
            }

            setPayRate(payRate);
        }
        catch(EmptyNameException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: the employee's name cannot be blank");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(InvalidEmployeeIdException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: the employee's id must be above 0");
            System.exit(1);
        }
        catch(InvalidPayRateException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: the payrate must not be negative nor exceed 25");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        setEmployeeId(employeeId);
        setPayRate(payRate);
    }

    public double getGrossPay()
    {
        return payRate * hours;
    }

    public int getEmployeeId()
    {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public int getHours()
    {
        return hours;
    }

    public double getPayRate()
    {
        return payRate;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId)
    {
        try
        {
            if(employeeId <= 0)
            {
                throw new InvalidEmployeeIdException();
            }

            this.employeeId = employeeId;
        }
        catch(InvalidEmployeeIdException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Numericals in ID must be between 0-9 and letters must be between A-M");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void setHours(int hours)
    {
        try
        {
            if(hours < 0 || hours > 84)
            {
                throw new InvalidHoursException();
            }

            this.hours = hours;
        }
        catch(InvalidHoursException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: Hours Cannot be negative or greater than 84");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void setPayRate(double payRate)
    {
        try
        {
            if(payRate < 0 || payRate > 25)
            {
                throw new InvalidPayRateException();
            }

            this.payRate = payRate;
        }
        catch(InvalidPayRateException e)
        {
            System.err.println("Error: Hourly Rate Cannot be negative or greater than 25");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    public void setName(String name)
    {
        try
        {
            if(name.isEmpty())
            {

                            throw new EmptyNameException();
            }

            this.name = name;
        }
        catch(EmptyNameException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: the employee's name cannot be blank");
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are correct.  You need to represent the id as a String, not an int.  Read up on [Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html)

Comment: You should not catch exceptions explicitly thrown by your code in the same method. The purpose of exceptions is to signal method's caller that something went wrong.

Comment: I think using a regex is better to handle EmployeID's format error